# Set timer on Buttons

Tags: c#

I have created some button dynamically  now I want to show all these buttons one by one . 
how could i use delay function . I use thread.sleep in loop . but it make delay for all buttons but I want to make delay for each button. I am using C# visual studio 2012

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{               
   btn[i] = new Button();
   btn[i].Text = i.ToString();
   btn[i].Click += Form1_Click;
   this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn[i]);
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}  //closing of code
```

Comment: Don't use Thread.Sleep() on your main UI thread or you'll block events and refreshes in the window. Use a Timer control instead with an interval, and on the Timer's Tick event handle the adding of one button, and on the next event raised the next, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You're currently blocking the UI thread - don't do that.

Instead, I suggest you use a timer. For example:

```
class Foo : Form
{
    private int nextButtonToShow = 0;
    private Timer timer;
    private Button[] buttons;

    internal Foo()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += ShowNextButton;
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ShowNextButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Set location etc
        Button button = new Button { Text = nextButtonToShow.ToString() };
        button.Click += ...;
        buttons[i] = button;
        Controls.Add(button);
        nextButtonToShow++;
        if (nextButtonToShow == buttons.Length)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(You should make sure you dispose of the timer when the form is disposed, too.)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Microsoft's reactive framework (look for Rx-Main on NuGet).

```
var addButtons =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Take(10)
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current);

addButtons.Subscribe(i =>
{
    btn[i] = new Button();
    btn[i].Text = i.ToString();
    btn[i].Click += Form1_Click;
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn[i]);
});
```